# How to make a shortcut of a given command?

Tags: bash, terminal, automator

I made a shell script named mkwebdir which creates a folder with html css and js files. Here the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

dirName="$1"

mkdir $dirName
cd $dirName

touch index.html style.css script.js

echo "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"style.css\">
  <meta charset=\"utf-8\" />
  <title>${dirName}</title>
</head>
<body>

  <script src=\"script.js\"></script>
</body>
</html>" >> index.html
```

I would like to create a shortcut or a dropbox option which receives an input for the folder name. I tried to use automator but I have trouble getting the folder name as an argument.
[automator image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVowy.jpg)

Comment: Don't forget to quote the use of `"$dirName"` everywhere

Comment: I'd also abort if the directory cannot be created: `mkdir "$dirName" || { echo "Cannot create $dirName" >&2; exit 1; }`

Comment: and add the `-p` flag: `mkdir -p "$dirName" ||  { echo "Cannot create $dirName" >&2; exit 1; }`

Comment: what do you mean with a shortcut or a dropbox option?

Answer (score 0):

You can alias the script in your .bashrc file like this:

```
alias neatscript="/home/myname/dirtoscript/script.sh"
```